# Cucumber tags: Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String

Tags: cucumber

Under `@CucumberOptions`, while using **tags** option to execute only some set of tests, ex: Smoke tests. I have written tags code as mentioned below:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = {"@SmokeTest"} // <<< Type mismatch: cannot convert from String[] to String
        )
```

But i am getting a type mismatch error.

Comment: You shouldn't use images for text. They're hard to read on some devices and impossible to search for.

Comment: Image text in the question is better way to show the error. Are you talking about 'Answer' screenshot. I will update my answer, Thanks

Comment: Nah. Images can't be read on a phone or screen reader. You may as well apply some ASCII art to make the location of the error clear.

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Thanks for information. I will follow the same going forward.

Answer (score 9):

To Fix this problem, do not use curly braces for tags. Just write code for tags like below code

```
@CucumberOptions(
        tags = "@SmokeTest and @End2End"
        )
```

I am not getting any error after removing curly braces.

Comment: If I have 7 tags total in my feature files. It will be difficult to write their relation in runner class. E.g. `"@Smoke not @Sanity and @Chrome or @Firefox and @qa not @stage"`
Also, everytime I want to change the relation I need to commit the Runner class. Is there a way to do it from command line in terminal.

Comment: didn't work, filter command didn't pick it up

Comment: @paul  Use,
mvn test -Dcucumber.filter.tags="(@cucumber or @gherkin) and not @salad"

Answer (score 0):

Solution is as below
i.e. replace {} covering the tags in Runner file with ()

tags=("@smoke and @functional")

Snippet

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        features="src/test/resources/Feature",
        glue={"StepDefination"},
        tags=("@Functional or @Sanity"),
                monochrome = true,
                plugin= {"pretty", "junit:target/JUNITReports/report.xml",
                 "json:target/JSONResports/report.json",
                 "html:target/HTMLReports/report.html"},
        dryRun=false
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In previous versions, the use of curly braces was there but with new versions, tags are used as simple text, with no need for any curly braces.
Instead of curly brackets, use small brackets it would work.